# Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at InstructionMemory.vhd(31): loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations

Tags: vhdl, quartus, assembler

Can someone help me solve this problem?

Its my code below:

```
library ieee;
library std;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

--
entity InstructionMemory is
    port (
        clk, rst : in std_logic;
        address : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        instr_out : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end entity;
architecture aim of InstructionMemory is

    type instr_mem is array(0 to 20) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    signal imem : instr_mem := (others => (others => '0'));

begin
    process (clk)
        file file_pointer : text;
        variable line_content : string (1 to 32);
        variable line_num : line;
        variable i : integer := 0;
        variable j : integer := 0;
        variable char : character := '0';
    begin

        file_open(file_pointer, "C:/Users/MM/Desktop/PF3/MIPS-Monocycle-32-bits-master/Testcases/instructions.txt", READ_MODE);
        while not endfile (file_pointer) loop -- this is line 31
            readline(file_pointer, line_num);
            READ(line_num, line_content);

            for j in 1 to 32 loop
                char := line_content(j);
                if (char = '0') then
                    imem(i)(32 - j) <= '0';
                else
                    imem(i)(32 - j) <= '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            i := i + 1;
        end loop;
        file_close(file_pointer); -- Close the file
        wait;
    end process;

    process (clk, rst)
    begin
        if rst = '1' then
            instr_out <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        elsif clk'EVENT and clk = '0' then

                assert (( (to_integer(unsigned(address)) mod 4194304)/4) < instr_mem'LENGTH)
                report  "Simulation has ended"
                severity ERROR;
            instr_out <= imem((to_integer(unsigned(address)) mod 4194304)/4);
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

this is line that apear the erro

```
    while not endfile (file_pointer) loop -- this is line 31
```

this is the size of intructions, 22 lines.

00000000111100000000100010010011

00000001010000000000100100010011

00000000101000000000100110010011

00000000010100000000101000010011

00000000001000000000101010010011

00010000000000000000111010010111

11111110110011101000111010010011

00000000000010101010111000110011

00000010000011100001110001100011

00000000010010101010111000010011

00000010000011100000100001100011

00000000001011100001001100010011

00000001110100110000001100110011

00000000000000110010001010000011

00000000000000101000000001100111

00000001010010011000010000110011

00000001100000000000000001101111

00000001001001001000010000110011

00000001000000000000000001101111

01000001001001001000010000110011

00000000100000000000000001101111

01000001010010011000010000110011

Comment: How long is your instructions.txt file (in numberfs of lines)? Are you simulating this or trying to force this through synthesis? If simulating: what simulator are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that, I mistake, but I put right now, thanks! 
I am trying to compile the code using the quartus II tool to do the synthesis of the code, but every time I try to get this error.

Comment: While loops are historically not synthesis eligible (as in Quartus II). Specifically excluded in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (now withdrawn). Your code doesn't analyze for synthesis, the process having both a sensitivity list and a wait statement.  Commenting out the sensitivity list allows simulation. Note instr_mem is an array of 21 values, providing 22 will cause a range constraint error at run time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to synthesize.  File access is not synthesizable.  "Compilation" in Quartus (and Vivado and similar tools) tries to convert the RTL, such as your VHDL, into hardware resources.

What you have might be applicable to simulation, but it is not appropriate for synthesis.